# Is there a programmatic method to detect a click on a Notification Center bubble and run a custom action under Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, customization, twitter, notifications

I appreciate that Notification Center is in its infancy but I was wondering if anyone had any idea how to intercept clicks on the "bubbles" that are generated and run your own actions.

Specifically, I'd like to be able to launch a local Twitter client rather than the website when clicking on a tweet notification?

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic according to the FAQ, you might get better results on Stack Overflow anyway.

Comment: Questions about programming, development, and listing your apps on the App Store are off topic for Ask Different. That said, questions about scripting, modifying `.plist`s, etc to  modify your system as an end user are very much on-topic. If you're asking how to do this as part of writing a program, you're in the wrong place, but if you're asking, as an end user, how to hack your system so NC launches your favorite client instead of the website, you're not off-topic (although I'm doubtful there will be an easy answer to your question)

Comment: Daniel - I am indeed asking for an end user hacky way to achieve my stated goal ideally via Apple script or some other simple OS customisation tool.